# How to set class instances in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

If I have a data type which has a list, then want to make it in stance of class `Show`, I am trying this but it is giving an error:

```
data Mlist a = Mlist [a]
m = Mlist [1, 2, 3]


instance Show Mlist where
    show (Mlist xs) = xs

-- m should now be {1, 2, 3}
```

Does anyone see the problem?

Comment: Why not just derive the Show instance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you just need this:

```
instance Show a => Show (Mlist a) where
    show (Mlist xs) = show xs
```

`Show a =>` means that this will make `Mlist a` an instance of `Show` when `a` is already an instance of `Show`.  In other words, `Show (Mlist a)` depends on `Show a`.

Also, you want to show the `xs` list, using the existing instance of `Show [a]`, which incidentally is declared `instance Show a => Show [a] where...`.  So you need to use `show xs`.

Comment: I tried that and got this error: MList' is not applied to enough type arguments The first argument of Show' should have kind *', but MList' has kind * -> *' In the instance declaration for Show MList'.

Answer (score 2):

The constructor for `Mlist a` is called `Mlist`, so write that instead of `mlist` in your pattern match. Likewise, there's no `MList` defined, so fix that too.

Moreover, it is `Mlist a`, not `Mlist`, that is an instance of `Show`, and only when `a` is. So you want `instance (Show a) => Show (Mlist a) where ...`

Comment: Then I get an error
    `MList' is not applied to enough type arguments
    The first argument of `Show' should have kind `*',
    but `MList' has kind `* -> *'
    In the instance declaration for `Show MList'

Answer (score 0):

Let's consult the definition of the `Show` class, just using `show` method for now:

```
class Show a where
    show :: a -> String
```

When you write `instance Show MList`, you substitute `MList` for every `a`, so the type signature for `show` would become:

```
show :: MList -> String
```

Aha!  There's a problem!  `MList` is not a valid type, but `MList Char` is, which means we need to fix our `instance` to say:

```
instance Show (MList Char) where ...
    show (Mlist xs) = xs
```

Edit: This is incorrect, because it does not handle `Int`s like you requested.  `gspr`'s answer is the right one.

Comment: I tried that and am getting:     Illegal instance declaration for `Show (Mlist Char)'
      (All instance types must be of the form (T a1 ... an)
       where a1 ... an are *distinct type variables*,
       and each type variable appears at most once in the instance head.
       Use -XFlexibleInstances if you want to disable this.)
    In the instance declaration for `Show (Mlist Char)'

Comment: I don't think he wants an instance just for `Mlist Char`. Even his example is for `Mlist Int`.

Comment: @gspr Oops, you are both right.  I missed the fact that he was using Ints.  Fortunately, you have the right answer.